# Express a surface integral of an axisymmetric function on an axisymmetric surface?

Tags: integration, surface-integrals, cylindrical-coordinates

An axisymmetric surface is represented by continuous and smooth function $z=F(r)$, where $0\le r \le R$, in a cylindrical coordinate $(r,z)$.

Now, I need to calculate the surface integral of an axisymmetric function $g(r)$, which is defined on the surface $z=F(r)$, with the follow expression
$$G=2 \pi \int_0^R r (1+F_r^2)^{1/2}g(r) \mathrm{d} r.$$
Is it true? Thank you very much.

Comment: No, it is not true, it should be $F'(r)$ instead of $\left(1 + F_r^2\right)^{1/2}.$ If you start from integral by $dz,$ you could see why (especially if you try to plot the surface in projection to $xz$ plane).

Comment: @AlexanderRodin, it's correct. I'd answer the question, but I am not very sure how to formalize it. $F$ is a function of $r$ and $\theta$, the surface integrals for such functions are treated with $\sqrt{F^2_r+F^2_\theta+1}·rdrd\theta$ as element of surface.

Comment: @RafaBudría Yes, I was mistaken. I have added a derivation of the expression as an answer.

Comment: @RafaBudría, Here, $F(r)$ is an axisymmetric function w.r.t. $\theta$, so the element of surface should be $2\pi (1+F_r^2)^{1/2}rdr$

Comment: Yes, and that's the reason for $F_\theta=0$

Answer (score 0):

Let's describe the surface by a vector function
$${\bf x}(r, \phi) = r\cos\phi\ {\bf e}_x + r\sin\phi\ {\bf e}_y + F(r) {\bf e}_z.$$

At each point $(r, \phi)$ [tangent vectors](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TangentVector.html) corresponding to each of these two coordinates are
$${\bf T}_r = \frac{\partial}{\partial r}{\bf x}(r, \phi) = \cos \phi \ {\bf e}_x + \sin \phi\ {\bf e}_y + F'(r)\ {\bf e}_z,\\
{\bf T}_\phi = \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}{\bf x}(r, \phi) = -r \sin \phi \ {\bf e}_x + r \cos \phi\ {\bf e}_y.$$

The surface integral can be [expressed through these tangent vectors](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SurfaceIntegral.html) as
$$\int\limits_S g({\bf x})\ dS = \iint\limits_S g(r) \left|{\bf T}_r \times {\bf T}_\phi\right|\ dr \ d\phi. $$

Calculating the cross product in ${\bf e}_x, {\bf e}_y, {\bf e}_z$ basis and taking its norm it is easy to obtain that

$${\bf T}_r \times {\bf T}_\phi = \left|
\begin{matrix}
{\bf e}_x & {\bf e}_y & {\bf e}_z \\
\cos \phi & \sin \phi\ & F'(r) \\
-r\sin \phi  &  r\cos \phi\ & 0
\end{matrix}
\right| = r\ F'(r)\cos\phi\ {\bf e}_x - r\ F'(r)\sin\phi\ {\bf e}_y + r\
 {\bf e}_z$$
and $$\left|{\bf T}_r \times {\bf T}_\phi\right| = r\sqrt{1 + \left(F'(r)\right)^2},$$
so it is possible to substitute this expression to the integral and integrate by $\phi$ from $0$ to $2\pi:$
$$\iint\limits_S g(r) \left|{\bf T}_r \times {\bf T}_\phi\right|\ dr \ d\phi  =
\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} d\phi \int\limits_{0}^{R} dr\  g(r)\ r \sqrt{1 + \left(F'(r)\right)^2} 
= 2\pi \int\limits_{0}^R g(r)\ r \sqrt{1 + \left(F'(r)\right)^2}\ dr.$$

Comment: In the third equation, $r$ is missing in two places.

Comment: @RafaBudría Thank you, I updated the answer.

Comment: @AlexanderRodin Thanks for your detail derivation. So the "guess" answer in my post should be true, because it is the same as your general answer. To avoid any ambiguity, I have added a product sign before the the last line.